# Why is my wtforms error handling not working?

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am trying to build a flask login and registration system. Everything works except when the user gives an incorrect input to the forms then there will be an error since there is no working error handling yet. I am using wtforms and here is the registration form class:

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(),Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4)])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')
```

And this is the registration route

```
@app.route('/register',  methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    else:
        return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

I have tired to handle the errors in htmlbut every time the user gives the incorrect input then it show this error message "TypeError: The view function for 'register' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement." Here is my html form:

```
        <form action="/register" method="POST">
          <h1>Create Account</h1>
          {{ form.hidden_tag() }} {% if form.username.errors %} {{
          form.username(placeholder="Username", class="is-invalid") }} {% for
          error in form.username.errors %}
          <span>{{ error }}</span>
          {% endfor %} {% else %} {{ form.username(placeholder="Username") }} {%
          endif %} {% if form.email.errors %} {{ form.email(placeholder="Email",
          class="is-invalid") }} {% for error in form.email.errors %}
          <span>{{ error }}</span>
          {% endfor %} {% else %} {{ form.email(placeholder="Email") }} {% endif
          %} {% if form.password.errors %} {{
          form.password(placeholder="Password", class="is-invalid") }} {% for
          error in form.password.errors %}
          <span>{{ error }}</span>
          {% endfor %} {% else %} {{ form.password(placeholder="Password") }} {%
          endif %} {% if form.confirm_password.errors %} {{
          form.confirm_password(placeholder="Confirm Password",
          class="is-invalid") }} {% for error in form.confirm_password.errors %}
          <span>{{ error }}</span>
          {% endfor %} {% else %} {{ form.confirm_password(placeholder="Confirm
          Password") }} {% endif %}

          <div>{{ form.submit(class="signup") }}</div>
        </form>
```

Any response or help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every view must return something. Yours returns nothing if method is post but doesn't validate. It is a logical problem, not related to wtforms.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    else:
        return 'oops'
else:
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Okay, that solves the error, thanks! But unfortunately the error message still doesn't show. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You mean the validation errors? Just return the template. Yours seems to be ready to display them.

Comment: Yeah I change the logic in the route into
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('register'))
But the validation errors is still not showing.

Comment: You have to pass the form. https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/crash_course/

Comment: Oh right, I completely forgot. Thanks!